# Account creation flow for semi-internal applications

Tags: account-security, user-management

We are developing an application that is to be used internally at our clients companies, but will be exposed as a public accessible website.

We have some clients who wish to use local accounts on our website (as opposed to some SSO solution like Azure AD), and we're discussing how to set up the account creation flow to maximize security, since it is one of our salespoints.

When a new client gets access to the system, they get the credentials for a "root" administrator account, and we then leave it up to them to create all other accounts the clients wish to have. Once an account is created, they can potentially immediately access some pretty confidential information from the company that other accounts may have shared with them.

One suggestion was to have the following workflow:

1. Administrator creates the user account (fills in email etc.)
2. While creating the user, the system sends a welcome email to the user
3. After creation, the administrator is shown an OTP for the user, which the administrator then can send to the user via some* other channel
4. When the user logs in the first time, they are forced to reset their password and verify their email

(*The idea is that the administrator will send it via Teams, Slack or some other IM app)

This approach uses multiple paths to communicate the login information to the user (email sent from our email server, password sent via IM, the company's internal email server, or some other means), guarding against sending the login information to someone unintended. The drawback is that it is very heavy on the administrator, since they have to communicate the password to each user.

Another approach would be:

1. Administrator creates the user account (fills in email etc.)
2. The system sends a welcome email to the user
3. The user registers themselves with the system (enters email and password), only emails that the administrator has created in step 1 are accepted, and the user is required to verify their email

This approach is a lot lighter on the administrator, but also does not have any safeguards that the person signing up with the email is the intented person (e.g. if the administrator mistypes the email or the emails are intercepted).

The questions are:

1. Is option 1 so much better than option 2 from a security view?
2. Is option 2 is good enough (are we just overcomplicating things/being paranoid)?
3. Are there other account creation flows that are better suited for internal applications?

Comment: What option is best for you depends on many details which are unknown in your case. How much one should invest in securing an account depends on the costs associated with a compromised account and the risk that the account gets compromised. The higher the value of the data, the higher the costs of compromise and the more lucrative it is for an attacker. But  if the users would download and arbitrarily share the data protected by the account or the account credentials anyway, then investing in a more secure account setup will probably not help much.

Comment: As @SteffenUllrich said, a lot of clarifications are required in order to provide an answer. However, can you please answer the following: (1) how do you communicate the initial "root" account to your client? (2) why should the admin create the user accounts? (3) how does the admin verify that the receipient of the OTP is the intented one?